# struct in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, struct, x86, masm, irvine32

I need to know the syntax of struct in assembly language . Also I need to know how to make array of struct and this struct will contain 4 variables each of them will carry an integer number .. How can I do this ?

new update :

can you tell me what is the wrong with this code please on the line mov arr[edx].x1 , [ebx] it give me an error saying invalid instruction operand and this is the whole code
     INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
     INCLUDE macros.inc

```
.DATA
line struct 
x1 byte ?
x2 byte ?
x3 byte ?
x4 byte ?
line ends

arr2 byte 16 DUP (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
arr line 4 DUP (<0,0,0,0>)

.CODE

main PROC

mov ebx,offset arr2
mov edx ,type arr

mov ecx,4
l:
mov arr[edx].x1 , [ebx]
inc ebx
mov arr[edx].x2 , [ebx]
inc ebx
mov arr[edx].x3 , [ebx]
inc ebx
mov arr[edx].x4 , [ebx]
inc ebx
inc edx
loop l 
mov edx ,offset arr
mov ecx,4
l1:
movzx eax, byte PTR arr[edx].x1
call writeint
movzx eax, byte PTR arr[edx].x2
call writeint
movzx eax, byte PTR arr[edx].x3
call writeint
movzx eax, byte PTR arr[edx].x4
call writeint
inc edx
loop l1

exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Which architecture, platform, and assembler are you programming for?  There is no general answer to this question as structures are not a thing the machine knows about, so if an assembler supports structures, it does so however it wants.

Comment: I guess its MASM .. I code in visual studio using irvine library

Comment: Sounds good!  I've added the correct tags for this combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example source file (Visual Studio 2015)

```
        title   xmpl
        .586p
        .model FLAT

;       include C libraries
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames
        includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions.lib    ;for scanf, printf, ...

xmpl    struct                          ;delcare structure (nothing initialized)
x0      dword   ?
x1      dword   ?
x2      dword   ?
x3      dword   ?
xmpl    ends

        .data
axmpl   xmpl    30 dup ({0,0,0,0})      ;array of 30 structs (init to zeroes)

        .code
_main   proc    near
        lea     ebx,axmpl               ;ebx points to first instance in array
        mov     eax,(xmpl ptr [ebx]).x0 ;eax = axmpl[0].x0
;       ...
        xor     eax,eax                 ;exit from main
        ret
_main   endp

        end
```

---

updated example:

```
line    struct 
x1      byte    ?
x2      byte    ?
x3      byte    ?
x4      byte    ?
line    ends

        .DATA
arr2    byte    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
arr     line    4 DUP ({0,0,0,0})

        .CODE

main    PROC

        mov     ebx,offset arr2
        mov     edx,offset arr

        mov     ecx,4
l:
        mov     al,[ebx]
        mov     [edx].line.x1,al
        inc     ebx
        mov     al,[ebx]
        mov     [edx].line.x2,al
        inc     ebx
        mov     al,[ebx]
        mov     [edx].line.x3,al
        inc     ebx
        mov     al,[ebx]
        mov     [edx].line.x4,al
        inc     ebx
        add     edx,sizeof line
        loop    l 
        mov     edx ,offset arr
        mov     ecx,4
l1:
        movzx   eax,[edx].line.x1
        call    writeint
        movzx   eax,[edx].line.x2
        call    writeint
        movzx   eax,[edx].line.x3
        call    writeint
        movzx   eax,[edx].line.x4
        call    writeint
        add     edx,sizeof line
        loop    l1
;       ...
```

alternate syntax used before update:

```
        mov     (line ptr [edx]).x1,al
```

using assume:

```
        assume  edx:ptr line
;       ...
        mov     [edx].x1,al
;       ...
        loop    l1
        assume  edx:nothing
```

Comment: where I should write this block of code .. in .DATA or .CODE ?

Comment: @MaryMikhail - I updated my example to include a complete source file, but one that uses the VS C library (it calls _main). I had to change the names since `c` is reserved (probably carry flag). `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` is needed for the library versions of scanf, printf, ..., as VS2015 and later now by default inline scanf and prinft in stdio.h in a complicated manner that would be difficult to implement in assembly.

Comment: I updated my question , Do you know how to fix my code ?

Comment: @MaryMikhail - I updated my answer. There is no memory to memory move instruction, except for movs?, so you need to load into a register, then store it.

Comment: thanks you so much this code is the base of my project  , thanks alot

Comment: I have a small question when I debug this code on visual studio , and then I add watch at  this part "(line ptr [edx]).x1" I don't know why it says that x1 is undefined and also the same for x2,x3,x4 but the code give me the correct output

Comment: @MaryMikhail - the debugger uses C syntax, so you can't just click on a line to setup a watch. You can set a breakpoint or use run to cursor to stop at a line in the program. Then click on debug, quickwatch and then for the expression enter `(line *)edx` to display the entire structure pointed to by edx, or enter `((line *)edx)->x1` to display (line ptr [edx]).x1. Note I updated my answer to show alternative syntax for the assembler code, such as using `[edx].line.x1` .

Comment: @MaryMikhail - you can also open a memory window to view the entire array. Again while stopped on a line of code, click on debug, windows, memory, memory1, and enter `&arr` to view memory starting at the array of structures.